# MySQL 5.7 performance issue with 300 GB Innodb

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, query-performance

We have a database running on MysSQL 5.7. The database size is around 300 GB, running on a dedicated Linux server (RHEL 6) with 144 GB RAM, 16 CPUs and 15 GB swap size.

The server is busy throughout the day with a minimum of 50 connections. Most of the queries have indexes and are optimized once weekly. But we are still facing a performance issue.

So requesting a review of the `my.cnf` configuration and please suggest any changes.

#### `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
basedir=/usr
datadir=/sql/mysql/data57
socket=/sql/mysql/data/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 4000M
max_allowed_packet = 5120M
table_open_cache = 4000
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer_size =8M
join_buffer_size=128M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 100
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_type="ON"
query_cache_min_res_unit=20K
query_prealloc_size=40K
query_alloc_block_size=40K
max_connections=300
sql_mode = ""
interactive_timeout = 28800
wait_timeout = 7200
connect_timeout = 60
default_password_lifetime=0
old_passwords=2
lower_case_table_names=1
tmpdir=/tmpfs
tmp_table_size=20G
max_heap_table_size=170M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=100G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=6562M
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=180
net_buffer_length=8K
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=180
federated


log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/sql/mysql/data/mysql.sock

[mysql.server]
user=mysql
basedir=/usr
log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed
server-id=1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=1G

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size=1024M
sort_buffer_size=256K
read_buffer=8M
write_buffer=8M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

#### Query

```
 SELECT year_no              AS "Year",
       month_no             AS "Month",
       area                 AS "Area",
       hq                   AS "Headquarters",
       region               AS "Region",
       depot                AS "Depot Name",
       aw                   AS "Dist Name",
       ss_channel           AS "Channel",
       sales.classification AS "Classification",
       sales.beat           AS "Beat",
       sales.salesman       AS "Salesman",
       sales.cust           AS "Retailer UID",
       Sum(qty)             AS "Qty",
       Sum(amt)             AS "Amount"
FROM   sales
       JOIN date_tbl
         ON dt = sales.dt
       JOIN or_areas
         ON area = sales.area
       JOIN hq
         ON hq = sales.hq
       JOIN or_regions
         ON region = sales.region
       JOIN depot
         ON depot = sales.depot
       JOIN or_aws
         ON aw = sales.aw
       JOIN prods
         ON sku = sales.sku
       JOIN prod_grp
         ON product_group = sales.product_group
       JOIN brand
         ON brand = sales.brand
       JOIN dsm
         ON ( salesman = sales.salesman )
       JOIN cust
         ON retailer = sales.retailer
WHERE  ss_inv_status IN ( 1, 3, -3 )
       AND ss_cust_name IS NOT NULL
       AND cal_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
       AND sales.zone IN ( ? )
       AND sales.region IN ( ? )
       AND sales.depot IN ( ? )
       AND sales.zone IN ( ? )
       AND sales.distributor_division = ?
       AND sales.brand IN ( ? )
GROUP  BY year_no,
          month_no,
          aw,
          sales.cust,
          prod,
          cal_date;
```

The `?` are place holders and the values are entered as inputs.

#### Explain

[image]

#### More information

- The performance problem is very big queries, which take 30 mins to execute.
- These are report queries which are generated on daily basis.
- It is not a DW system.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE sales`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have found an example of "over-normalization" and why it is bad to "normalize continuous values" such as dates.

I recommend you abandon `date_tbl` and pull a date into `sales`.  Also get rid of separate columns for `year_no` and `month_no`; instead compute them as needed.

Once you have done that, some of these may be useful:

```
INDEX(cal_date)
INDEX(brand, cal_date)
INDEX(zone, cal_date)
```

It depends on what `?` are likely to be.  If, say, `brand` is frequently a single item, then `(brand, cal_date)` is likely to be the most useful.

Have you measured *any* improvement after `OPTIMIZE TABLE`?  I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks Rick James.. I will use your recommendations.. And also 90% of query execution is spent on "Creating sort index" state. Why is it so??

Comment: Because the thing that displays the "state" is lame -- it almost never says what it is _really_ doing.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the performance issues are aggravated by my.cnf values.
Consider adding in [mysqld] section

```
innodb_change_buffer_size_max = 5  # from 25 to reduce set aside for I, D, U ops
```

With 100G of IBPoolSize this 'set-aside' drops from 25G to 5G available for 
Insert, Delete, Update maintenance.  The other 20% will be available for rows of data in the pool.

Consider removing this list to allow defaults to work for you:

```
key_buffer_size = 4000M
max_allowed_packet = 5120M  # with 144G RAM, /5G = 28 active connections = OOM
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer_size = 8M
join_buffer_size = 128M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
query_cache_min_res_unit=20K
net_buffer_length=8K
```

Also, since you have no intention of using Query Cache, add

```
have_query_cache = 0   # to eliminate CPU overhead when this is Yes
```

Use of mysqlcalculator.com with present my.cfg values indicates you would need about ~ 210G of memory to support your 300 planned max_connections.

@veerendra kumar, have you been able to make any of these changes?  Any improvement?